# GemFire; starting the REST API server issues

Tags: gemfire

I have installed Gemfire 9.x on Ubuntu  and was able to start locator and Server but was unable to start the REST server with the command option start server --name=server1 --start-rest-api=true 
--http-service-port=8080 --http-service-bind-address=localhost .

In the server logs I see below error message. Please guide me i the right way.

Thnak you.

Error message..

[info 2017/07/10 13:36:58.131 EDT server1  tid=0x1] geode-web-api war found: /opt/pivotal/pivotal-gemfire-9.0.4/tools/Extensions/geode-web-api-9.0.4.war

[info 2017/07/10 13:36:58.144 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Logging initialized @4705ms

[info 2017/07/10 13:36:58.210 EDT server1  tid=0x1] jetty-9.3.6.v20151106

[info 2017/07/10 13:36:58.747 EDT server1  tid=0x1] NO JSP Support for /gemfire-api, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet

[info 2017/07/10 13:36:58.907 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'geode'

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.560 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Context refreshed

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.574 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.580 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Scanning for api listing references

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.721 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: deleteUsingDELETE_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.765 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: readUsingGET_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.810 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: createUsingPOST_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.818 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: deleteUsingDELETE_2

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.824 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: listUsingGET_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.848 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: updateUsingPUT_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:01.888 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@49754e74{/gemfire-api,[file:///home/telirisuser/mygemfire/server1/GemFire_telirisuser/services/http/10.160.3.181_7070_gemfire-api/webapp/, jar:file:///home/telirisuser/mygemfire/server1/GemFire_telirisuser/services/http/10.160.3.181_7070_gemfire-api/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-swagger-ui-2.6.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}{/opt/pivotal/pivotal-gemfire-9.0.4/tools/Extensions/geode-web-api-9.0.4.war}

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:02.182 EDT server1  tid=0x1] NO JSP Support for /geode, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:02.229 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'geode'

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.502 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Context refreshed

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.518 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.528 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Scanning for api listing references

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.666 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: deleteUsingDELETE_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.717 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: readUsingGET_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.767 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: createUsingPOST_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.776 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: deleteUsingDELETE_2

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.783 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: listUsingGET_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.809 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Generating unique operation named: updateUsingPUT_1

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.857 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@353422fd{/geode,[file:///home/telirisuser/mygemfire/server1/GemFire_telirisuser/services/http/10.160.3.181_7070_geode/webapp/, jar:file:///home/telirisuser/mygemfire/server1/GemFire_telirisuser/services/http/10.160.3.181_7070_geode/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-swagger-ui-2.6.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}{/opt/pivotal/pivotal-gemfire-9.0.4/tools/Extensions/geode-web-api-9.0.4.war}

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.857 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Stopping the HTTP service...

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.859 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Stopped ServerConnector@2dbcee03{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{10.160.3.181:7070}

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.859 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'geode'

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.871 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@353422fd{/geode,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/pivotal/pivotal-gemfire-9.0.4/tools/Extensions/geode-web-api-9.0.4.war}

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.871 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'geode'

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.880 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@49754e74{/gemfire-api,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/pivotal/pivotal-gemfire-9.0.4/tools/Extensions/geode-web-api-9.0.4.war}

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.893 EDT server1  tid=0x1] Cache server connection listener bound to address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:40404 with backlog 1,000.

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.902 EDT server1  tid=0x1] ClientHealthMonitorThread maximum allowed time between pings: 60,000

[info 2017/07/10 13:37:04.908 EDT server1  tid=0x1] CacheServer Configuration:   port=40404 max-connections=800 max-threads=0 notify-by-subscription=true socket-buffer-size=32768 maximum-time-between-pings=60000 maximum-message-count=230000 message-time-to-live=180 eviction-policy=none capacity=1 overflow directory=. groups=[] loadProbe=ConnectionCountProbe loadPollInterval=5000 tcpNoDelay=true

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an error message in your logs. I think the problem is you need to bind to the IP address not `localhost` it's to do with NIC settings.

So like `start server --name=server1 --start-rest-api=true --http-service-port=8080 --http-service-bind-address=191.234.180.99 --server-bind-address=191.234.180.99`